# Change boxplot x axis labels alignment in r -ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, axis-labels

I'm new to using RStudio so please forgive me if I'm overlooking an obvious method of solving the problem.

I have produced a boxplot in r that is almost right, except I would like to change the alignment/or size of the x-axis labels/text.

I am currently using RStudio version 3.1, but something has changed since R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08) Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) as code from then, is not working for me.

There are 2 species and 5 treatments, the intention was to draw a box plot with interaction between species and treatment, lined up so that there was species 1 treat 1, species 2 treat 1, species 1 treat 2, species 2 treat 2 etc.

The code that has worked so far is:

```
pseudodata <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
pseudodata$agg_count <- rep(1:60, each=2)

data <- aggregate(pseudodata , by=list(pseudodata$agg_count), FUN=mean)

boxplot   (Force..N. ~ interaction(data$Species, data$Treatment), 
          data=data, col=(c("gold","darkgreen")),
          xlab="Species and Treatment", ylab="Force of detachment (N)")
```

Which produced a boxplot very similar to [Second boxplot with colour notched](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/boxplot.html)

However the x axis text labels do not all show, so I would like to set them at a 45o angle.

I have tried:

```
labels <- c("Helix.Copper", "Hibernica.Copper","Helix.Easy on", "Hibernica.Easy on",
            "Helix.Pegagraff", "Hibernica.Pegagraff", "Helix.Untreated", 
            "Hibernica.Untreated", "Helix.Zinc", "Hibernica.Zinc")

forceplot <- boxplot(Force..N. ~ interaction(data$Species, data$Treatment), 
        data=data,  # dataframe used
        xaxt="n", # suppress the default x axis
        col=(c("gold","darkgreen")),
        xlab="Species and Treatment", ylab="Force of detachment (N)")

Text(forceplot, par(“usr”)[3], labels = labels, srt = 45, 
        adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex=.9)
        )
axis(2)
```

But is doesn't appear to work and I don't know why.  If anyone has any ideas as to how to create this plot I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want. But does this approach help you?

```
library(ggplot2)

### Create a sample data
species <- rep(c("s1","s2"), each = 20, times = 5)
treatment <- rep(c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5"), each = 1, times = 40)
value <- runif(200, 100, 500)

foo <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,value))
foo$value <- as.numeric(foo$value)

### Draw boxplots
ana <- ggplot(foo, aes(x = species, y = value, fill = treatment)) +
    geom_boxplot()

ana
```